# Infragistics StackColumnChart show the wrong value

Tags: c#, charts, infragistics

I need an explanation about Infragistics, which I don't understand. I want to display several bars in a chart per month. The whole thing will be in my opinion a StackColumnChart:

[image: Pic1]

But is displayed incorrectly.

If I run the whole thing as a ColumnChart they are displayed correctly:

[image: pic2]

Is it possible that I get the same display also in the StackColumnChart?

Comment: Why is the one column add to the other ?

Comment: This is because of the way how data is organized on the _Stacked Column Chart_: the data added to show what the maximum value is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your chart is configured to show data values on charted items. This is how the data is organized on the `Stacked Column Chart`. But this default behavior you can change according to your requirements.

Make the following changes.

I suppose you already have the `Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.ChartTextAppearance chartTextAppearance1` declaration. If not you can add it by using the **Chart Wizard**.

The `chartTextAppearance1` will added later to the column chart appearance like that:

```
columnChartAppearance1.ChartText.Add(chartTextAppearance1);
```

Set the `chartTextAppearance1.ItemFormatString` to `<DATA_VALUE_ITEM>`:

```
chartTextAppearance1.ItemFormatString = "<DATA_VALUE_ITEM>";
```

This make it work as you was asking.

---

*Some additional information you can find here:* [Label Formatting](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/chart-label-formatting)